# AVAudioPlayer does not work with mp3's on documents folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer, nsurl

`AVAudioPlayer *player;
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            dir = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:targetSound];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dir isDirectory:YES];
[player setDelegate:self];
            player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:data error:nil];
            [player play];`
Here is my code. Xcode doesn't give any errors, but there is not any sound coming out.
Need your help, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are made mistake this chaage this `NSDocumentationDirectory` to `NSDocumentDirectory`

Comment: It's done man, thank you, just a mistake that I couldn't see.